# Empty lines or lines with symbols only have smaller font size in VS2013

Tags: fonts, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 source code editor empty lines or lines with only symbols, such as '{' or '#', have smaller font size than lines with alphanumeric characters.

I'm using "Classic Console" fixed-width font. This font does not have this problem in other applications and in VS2013 on my computer at work.

EDIT: Actually this problem occurs with any font.

[image: Inconsistent font size in VS]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have found the solution. It was caused by a default setting in Productivity Power Tools add-on.

[image]

Comment: This "fix" worked well - What a buggy "feature" though is this...

Comment: Very useful and evocative diagram ;) And thank you so much for choosing question and answer text that made it easy for me to discover this page on Google. +1

Comment: Oh but it was so productive!

Comment: In the 2017 version of the extension the options are called `Compress blank lines` and `Compress lines that do not have any alphanumeric characters`.. No restart of VS is required after changing this option :)